# Multiple nametype errors wordcloud in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, svm, word-cloud

I'm so confused. I'm trying to make a wordcloud of my dataset, but I keep getting errors I can't seem to figure out... The dataset is not text, it's a csv file.

I have a whole code above this one that cleans the data and add sentiment anaylsis columns etc. But this is the wordcloud part of my code:

```
#create wordcloud to see what kind of words apear in the reviews
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show_wordcloud(data, title = None):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='white',
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40,
        scale=3,
        random_state=42
    ).generate(str(data))


fig = plt.figure(1, figsize = (20,20))
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Review words')
if title:
        fig.suptitle(title, fontsize = 20)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top = 2.3)

plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.show()

#print wordcloud
show_wordcloud(reviews_df['review'])
```

The error from my Python terminal is:

```
>>> from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def show_wordcloud(data, title = None):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='white',
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40,
        scale=3,
        random_state=42
    ).generate(str(data))

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize = (20,20))
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Review words')
if title:
        fig.suptitle(title, fontsize = 20)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top = 2.3)

plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.show()
#print wordcloud

show_wordcloud(reviews_df['review'])
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> def show_wordcloud(data, title = None):
...     wordcloud = WordCloud(
...         background_color='white',
...         max_words=200,
...         max_font_size=40,
...         scale=3,
...         random_state=42
...     ).generate(str(data))
... 
>>> fig = plt.figure(1, figsize = (20,20))
>>> plt.axis('off')
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
>>> plt.title('Review words')
Text(0.5, 1.0, 'Review words')
>>> if title:
...         fig.suptitle(title, fontsize = 20)
...         fig.subplots_adjust(top = 2.3)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
**NameError: name 'title' is not defined**
>>> plt.imshow(wordcloud)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
**NameError: name 'wordcloud' is not defined**
>>> plt.show()
>>> #print wordcloud
>>> 
>>> show_wordcloud(reviews_df['review'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
**NameError: name 'reviews_df' is not defined**
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?? Could someone please help?

Comment: looks like an indentation error. everything from `fig = plt.figure...` down to `plt.show()` should be indented to the same level as `wordcloud = ...`

Comment: you also don't load your data into `review_df` anywhere in this script